# Cannot load spark-avro jars with databricksversion 10.4

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, databricks-connect

Currently, I am facing an issue since the `databricks-connect` runtime on our cluster was updated to 10.4. Since then, I cannot load the jars for spark-avro anymore. By Running the following code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.3.0").getOrCreate()
```

I get the following error:

```
The jars for the packages stored in: C:\Users\lazlo\.ivy2\jars
org.apache.spark#spark-avro_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-dc011dfd-9d25-4d6f-9d0e-354626e7c1f8;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found org.apache.spark#spark-avro_2.12;3.3.0 in central
    found org.tukaani#xz;1.8 in central
    found org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 156ms :: artifacts dl 4ms
    :: modules in use:
    org.apache.spark#spark-avro_2.12;3.3.0 from central in [default]
    org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 from central in [default]
    org.tukaani#xz;1.8 from central in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   3   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   3   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-dc011dfd-9d25-4d6f-9d0e-354626e7c1f8
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 3 already retrieved (0kB/5ms)
22/08/16 13:15:57 WARN Shell: Did not find winutils.exe: {}
```

...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Aifora/repositories/test_poetry/tmp_jars.py", line 4, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.3.0").getOrCreate()
  File "C:\Users\lazlo\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-poetry-vvodToDL-py3.8\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 229, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "C:\Users\lazlo\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-poetry-vvodToDL-py3.8\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 400, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\Users\lazlo\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-poetry-vvodToDL-py3.8\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 147, in __init__
    self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
  File "C:\Users\lazlo\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-poetry-vvodToDL-py3.8\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 210, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "C:\Users\lazlo\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-poetry-vvodToDL-py3.8\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 337, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "C:\Users\lazlo\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-poetry-vvodToDL-py3.8\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1568, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Users\lazlo\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\test-poetry-vvodToDL-py3.8\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
```

If important: I use a windows machine (Windows 11) and manage the packages via poetry. Here my pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "test_poetry"
version = "1.37.5"
description = ""
authors = [
     "lazloo xp <lazloo.xp@xxx.com>",
 ]

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "xxx_nexus"
url = "https://nexus.infrastructure.xxxx.net/repository/pypi-all/simple/"
default = true

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "==3.8.*"
databricks-connect = "^10.4"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one week of research, I found a solution by checking with a colleague about the environmental variables on his windows machine. It turned out that the following steps helped:

1. Copy a winutils.exe file to C:\Hadoop\bin (my colleague found it at some git repro)
2. Add C:\Hadoop\bin as HADOOP_HOME to the environment variables

Now everything runs smoothly